# How to use eclipse(cdt) with visual c++ 2015?

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, eclipse-cdt

I just install visual studio 2015, but I find it is not easy to build tiny projects.
So I want to use eclipse 4.5(cdt) with vc++ 2015
The cdt version is 8.7.

I assumble the include path and link library manually, but the project is still fail to build.

```
17:52:23 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project hw ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
link /debug /nologo /OUT:hw.exe "src\\hw.obj" "C:\\Program" Files(x86)\\Microsoft" Visual Studio "14.0\\VC\\lib" 
LINK : fatal error LNK1104:
```

beside vc\lib any other lib path I should include in library path?

Comment: I'm searching for the same answer, any info on stackoverflow.